# is there any option to get key values separately from a array of objects and make it as separate array of object within single quotes

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var Header =[
{
  "COL_1": "Name",
  "COL_2": "Subject",
  "COL_3": "likes",
  "COL_4": "city",
  
},
{
  "COL_1": "mohan",
  "COL_2": "maths",
  "COL_3": "3",
  "COL_4": "chennai",
  
}

  ];
```

expected output:

```
    var output=[
  {
  "COL_1":'Name,Subject,Likes,city'
  },
  {
  "COL_1":'mohan,maths,3,chennai'
  }
  ];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The single quotes thing just makes it easier for you to type without pressing the shift key. The quotes are virtually stripped off when concatenating. Of course, if you are putting the same quotes within the quotes on the outside, they need to be escaped. `console.log("some string "+'some "other\'s" string');` Notice you don't see the quotes unless they are inside of other quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map` and `Object.values`

```js
var Header = [
  {
    COL_1: "Name",
    COL_2: "Subject",
    COL_3: "likes",
    COL_4: "city",
  },
  {
    COL_1: "mohan",
    COL_2: "maths",
    COL_3: "3",
    COL_4: "chennai",
  },
];

const res = Header.map((obj) => {
  const [key] = Object.keys(obj);
  return {
    [key]: Object.values(obj).join(),
  };
});

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try out this:

```js
var Header =[
    {
        "COL_1": "Name",
        "COL_2": "Subject",
        "COL_3": "likes",
        "COL_4": "city",

    },
    {
        "COL_1": "mohan",
        "COL_2": "maths",
        "COL_3": "3",
        "COL_4": "chennai",

    }

];
let output = [];
Header.forEach(elem => {
    let str = '';
    Object.keys(elem).forEach(key => str += elem[key] + ',');
    output.push({COL_1: str});
});
console.log('output:', output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `map()` method on the original array. Then use the `Object.keys()` method to get the key for each object, and the `Object.values()` method to get the values from the object.
I would also recommend that you use ***const*** or ***let*** instead of ***var*** for variable declaration.

```js
const Header = [
  {
    "COL_1": "Name",
    "COL_2": "Subject",
    "COL_3": "likes",
    "COL_4": "city",

  },
  {
    "COL_1": "mohan",
    "COL_2": "maths",
    "COL_3": "3",
    "COL_4": "chennai",

  }
];

const output = Header.map((el) => {
  const key = Object.keys(el)[0];
  return {
    [key]: `${Object.values(el)}`
  }
});

console.log(output);
```